# actionbar icon image programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using this code to set alphas and typefaces to my actionbar views while I scroll my scrollview.

```
    int upId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("icon", "id", "android");
    if (upId > 0) {
        ImageView up = (ImageView) findViewById(upId);
        up.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }


    int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
    abTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    abTitle.setAlpha(0);
    abTitle.setTypeface(tf);
```

- Well, so far so good but I want to try to get the actionbar icon and I'm not being able to get the identifyer for the image view. Anyone can five me a hint on this?

Before you ask: I'm doing it this way because I want to keep my app the lowest sdk possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    logo = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_degradee);
    logo.setAlpha(0);

    getActionBar().setLogo(logo);
```

more easy then expected